# ちゃいけない expression

Tags: grammar

> やっちゃいけないことをやっちゃった。

I noticed that it uses 2 verbs. One is `遣る` and the other one is `ちゃう`. They can stand alone as an individual verbs or they can combined together as in the example sentence.

The way I make sense of `やっちゃいけない` is that it combines `遣る` and `ちゃう` to create a command telling someone to not do something. But, I don't understand how to make sense of `やっちゃった`. It still uses the same 2 verbs but when combined, they don't indicate a command and `ちゃった` is just a past tense of `ちゃう`, so why combine them into `やっちゃった` then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ちゃう is not a verb that can stand on its own, as far as I know, except in some dialects as a form of 違う.

Are you familiar with ～てしまう? This form, in this case, means the result was undesirable. The 過去形 being った is normal for godan verbs ending in う. It can contract to ちゃう.

Superficially やっちゃいけない may resemble it somewhat, but this やっちゃ is やっては. ～ては（駄目・いけない・ならない）is a form meaning 'must not', 'should not', etc. Are you familiar with this?

Accordingly, the sentence is something like 'I did something I shouldn't have.'

Answer (score 3):

ちゃう is not a verb -- やっちゃいけないこと is simply a reduction of やってはいけないこと "Something that must not be done". Your understanding of やっちゃいけない is not correct, as it is not a command in this context at all.

Accordingly the sentence simply translates to:

> やっちゃいけないことをやっちゃった
> I ended up doing something I wasn't meant to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's not wrong to say ちゃう is a verb, but it's a pretty misleading statement.  Also, ちゃう cannot stand on its own.  ちゃう is what is called a 補助動詞 or auxiliary verb and attaches to another verb to add a nuance to that verb.

ちゃう is in fact a contraction and colloquial form of the 補助動詞 てしまう, and denotes a regret or disappointment in the action/state the preceding verb represents.
補助動詞 follows the same conjugation pattern as the (regular) verbs, and both ちゃう and てしまう are godan-verbs.  Their ta-forms are ちゃった and しまった, respectively.

As for やる, you have the wrong やる.  遣る is an archaic verb means "to send a delegate," which I assume you expressed as "to command."  やる here is the plain やる which is pretty much the same as する in meaning: "to do."

To sum up, your やっちゃった =
やる vb. "do" + ちゃう aux. vb. *regret* + た particle *past*

By the way, ちゃ in やっ**ちゃ**いけない is not てしまう.  It's a contraction of ては.  A more formal way to say this would be やってはいけないこと.  ってはいけない or　ちゃいけない can be broken down even further by a linguist, but I think it's better for you to consider the whole thing as a coupla that means "must not" (prohibition).  So やっちゃいけないこと =
やる vb. "do" + っちゃいけない coupla "must not" + こと "thing"

This gives you a word-by-word translation of:
"[I] regrettably did a/the thing I must not have done."

On a side note, やっちゃった！ is an utterance you can say on the spot when you screw up something (e.g., drop a glass).  It's very close to "I did it!!!" in English.